# Remove non-printable characters from a converted string

Tags: c++, string, unicode, non-printing-characters

I need to convert a unicode string represented by `std::u16string` to `std::wstring` and filter out nonprintable characters. The way I do this is as below. In our real project I use ranges for convenience, so I'll keep them here as well:

```
std::wstring printable = std::u16string{...}
                       | ranges::to<std::wstring>()
                       | ranges::actions::remove_if([](const wchar_t ch) noexcept {
                           return !std::iswprint(ch);
                         });
```

My colleague doubts if this is ok and there won't be any unicode characters falsely treated as printable. Is this approach correct? Maybe I should first remove non-printable characters from `u16string` and then convert it to `wstring`? Or maybe it is better to use some unicode-specific function on `wstring` instead of `iswprint`?

Comment: Some unicode characters are encoded in more than one `wchar_t`...

Comment: You cannot do anything with Unicode unless you also know what **encoding** you are using. On the reasonable assumption that your `u16string` is encoded with UTF-16 then this will not work because some Unicode characters are not represented by a single `char16_t`.

Comment: You really cannot get anywhere with Unicode and C++ until you realise that C++ makes no assumptions at all about the encoding you are using. It's up to you to know what that is, and then pick the right function based on that knowledge. Unicode is a character set only, the encoding to use is up to you.